# Queue-like data structure with random access element removal

Tags: c++, data-structures

Is there a data structure like a queue which also supports removal of elements at arbitrary points? Enqueueing and dequeueing occur most frequently, but mid-queue element removal must be similar in speed terms since there may be periods where that is the most common operation. Consistency of performance is more important than absolute speed. Time is more important than memory. Queue length is small, under 1,000 elements at absolute peak load.In case it's not obvious I'll state it explicitly: random insertion is not required.

Have tagged C++ since that is my implementation language, but I'm not using (and don't want to use) any STL or Boost. Pure C or C++ only (I will convert C solutions to a C++ class.)

Edit: I think what I want is a kind of dictionary that also has a queue interface (or a queue that also has a dictionary interface) so that I can do things like this:

```
Container.enqueue(myObjPtr1);
MyObj *myObjPtr2 = Container.dequeue();
Container.remove(myObjPtr3);
```

Comment: Why not STL or Boost ? They are pure C++. Else you would need to write your own data structures.

Comment: No STL?  Then you'll have to write it yourself.  I'd go with a tree with updating counts of how many nodes are in the left child.  Should be log(n) everything.

Comment: `(I will wrap C solutions in a C++ class.)` I refuse to read any further

Comment: @TimKemp: Learn the STL and Boost.  They are really really good at what they do.

Comment: @TimKemp: If you don't know the STL, then you don't know C++. It's an essential part of the language's std lib, it's extensively used in just about every code written by others you'll ever look at, it's incredibly efficient, and once you overcome the (relatively small) initial hurdle of the somewhat funny syntax, it makes sense. Not using the STL in C++ is like not using classes: Yeah, you can do this, but then why write C++ in the first place? Not using boost, OTOH, means you're not using C++ to its fullest potential, and miss all the small, but necessary helpers that make life worthwhile.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry! If I promise not to start a debate can you explain your disgust? It is appropriate in my particular case, where I have just one instance of this container.

Comment: @sbi: STL is not part of the language or library. But we've been over this before.

Comment: @TimKemp: Because you're basically saying that you're actively going to write C with Classes, and I find that upsetting. We don't need more thin "C++" "OO" "wrappers" in the world :(

Comment: @sbi Quite right. I don't know C++ very well and never claimed to. Learning STL and Boost is on my to-do list, right below shipping the product. I have a small portion of C++ performing one specific task in a large ObjC codebase and right now it works very well, minus this container.

Comment: @TimKemp: Programming is about solving problems. Libraries are the parts of your problem that have been solved already. It’s wasteful and absurd not to use them when you can.

Comment: @Lightness: Yes, we've been there before, and I'm firmly in the STL-is-not-the-std-lib camp. However, most of the STL has been incorporated into the C++ std lib, which I consider to be part of C++ (it's the major part of the std paper, after all).

Comment: @sbi: The bit after your "however" is just as part of the "we've been there before" as the rest. Nobody ever disagreed that the standard library is part of C++. The whole point is that "incorporated" is a dangerous over-simplification. \*ahem\* anyway...

Comment: @Lightness: Of course it's a simplification. So?

Comment: @sbi: Not just a "simplification", but a _dangerous over-simplification_. I don't think that phrase requires any further qualification to make its proposed importance clear.

Comment: @Lightness: Not at all. The SGI STL effectively does not exist as a separate library for C++. When you say "STL", nobody is going to think "That template library from 1993, instead of the Standard library".

Comment: @DeadMG: You mean, instead of the _parts of the Standard Library that are containers, algorithms, functors and iterators?_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that double-link list is exactly what you want (assuming you do not want a priority queue):

1. Easy and fast adding elements to both ends
2. Easy and fast removal of elements from anywhere

You can use `std::list` container, but (in your case) it is difficult to remove an element
from the middle of the list if you only have a pointer (or reference) to the element (wrapped in STL's list element), but
you do not have an iterator. If using iterators (e.g. storing them) is not an option - then implementing a double linked list (even with element counter) should be pretty easy. If you implement your own list - you can **directly** operate on pointers to elements (each of them contains pointers to both of its neighbours). If you do not want to use Boost or STL this is probably the best option (and the simplest), and you have **control** of everything (you can even write your own block allocator for list elements to speed up things).

Comment: note that a linked list does not allow fast removal of "elements every where", because **finding** an element in the list is `O(n)`. If you are asked to delete element with value `k` [or index `i`], it will be `O(n)` to get to it.

Comment: Then you did not read my comment with understanding. If I have a pointer to a **list element** (which contains pointers to both of its neighbours) than what else do I need to find ?

Comment: OK this sounds interesting, thanks and the approach should work. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use an **order statistic tree**, an augmented tree structure that supports O(log n) random access to each element, along with O(log n) insertion and deletion at arbitrary points.  Internally, the order statistic tree is implemented as a balanced binary search treewith extra information associated with it.  As a result, lookups are a slower than in a standard dynamic array, but the insertions are much faster.

Hope this helps!

Comment: insertions/removals to ends are slower than a `deque`, but faster for the middle.

Comment: Thanks, got a reference implementation or paper anywhere? A search didn't turn up much on these beyond some other questions.

Comment: @Tim Kemp- I found this implementation in C: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/10379.  I've been wanting to implement this structure in C++ for a while, so I think I might do that when I have some free time (not sure how soon that will be).  If I do, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of a linked list and a hash table. In java it is called a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

The idea is simple, have a linked list of elements, and also maintain a `hash map` of `(key,nodes)`, where `node` is a pointer to the relevant node in the linked list, and `key` is the key representing this node.

Note that the basic implementation is a `set`, and some extra work will be needed to make this data structure allow dupes.

This data structure allows you both `O(1)` head/tail access, and both `O(1)` access to any element in the list. [all on average armotorized]

Comment: As an added note, this can be easily implemented with a `std::unordered_set` and a Boost.Intrusive list.

Comment: Just a thought - what happens if there are duplicate elements in the queue?  How would you differentiate between them?  Also, if you wanted to remove by index, how would you support this?

Comment: @templatetypedef: More work is needed to support duplicates - as I mentioned. A possible solution might be a `map<key,list<node>>` - but it suffers when your lists has many dupes. A removal by index is indeed problematic with a `LinkedHashSet` - I guess any solution to do it efficiently will require converting the list into a skip list [with index counting], which will result in decaying ops to `O(logn)`. There is an obvious trade-off here: The `O(1)` performance of the `LinkedHashSet` does not come for free.

Comment: this won't work if "random access" is by order, a.k.a., index of the element in the list